# ResNet model in keras and tf.keras give different output for the same image

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras, resnet

For a given image, I'm extracting ResNet features i.e. after all conv layers and global max pooling, which gives a 2048 length vector per image.

Earlier, I was using `keras==2.3.1` with backend `tensorflow==1.13.1`. Now, I've shifted to `tensorflow==2.0.0` since keras has been merged with tensorflow. I replaced my code with `tf.keras` instead of `keras`.

But now the features extracted are not the same as the features extracted earlier. ResNet is a model which is independent of tensorflow/keras or even pytorch for that matter. It's functionality is predefined. Why is this difference occuring? Are there any parameters that can be tweaked to get the same functionality?

**Edit 1**: Adding code

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
resnet_model = ResNet50(include_top=False)
```

Comment: What is the difference that you are seeing?

Comment: The output values are different. Do you want me to put a sample output? I thought it wouldn't add any extra information and so didn't add

Comment: Are you using the pre-trained network? Have you downloaded the imagenet weights?

Comment: Maybe dd the code you are using, there are changes in ResNet between versions, and maybe the weights have changed too, your assumption that the network is independent of the framework is not really true (there are multiple version of ResNet anyway).

Comment: @SajanGohil Yes, I'm using pretrained imagenet weights. I've updated my question with the code I'm using.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I'm using ResNet v1 only. Since I didn't change the ResNet version, should't I get the same behaviour with both keras and tf.keras. I've added code in the question. All I changed is the import statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The models themselves keep updating and the weights with better results are used. [Here](https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases) is the releases folder where you can see releases of different weight files. The folder linked is for keras, which is most probably also used by tf.keras. 
The problem you are facing is probably because of the version of library rather than method of calling the model.

For example, [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/blob/master/keras_applications/resnet50.py) you can find the keras_applications code and check the weight path which points to release v0.2(linked is keras but similarly for tensorflow.keras).

The older library versions have older links, updating the libraries also updates the paths.