# degraded accuracy performance with overfitting when downgrading from tensorflow 2.3.1 to tensorflow 1.14 or 1.15 on multiclass categorization

Tags: tensorflow

I made a script in `tensorflow 2.x` but I had to downconvert it to `tensorflow 1.x` (tested in `1.14` and `1.15`). However, the `tf1` version performs very differently (10% accuracy lower on the test set). See also the plot for train and validation performance (diagram is attached below).

Looking at the operations needed for the migration from `tf1` to `tf2` it seems that only the `Adam` learning rate may be a problem but I'm defining it explicitly [tensorflow migration](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate#keras_optimizer_lr)

I've reproduced the same behavior both locally on GPU and CPU and on colab. The keras used was the one built-in in tensorflow (`tf.keras`). I've used the following functions (both for train,validation and test), using a sparse categorization (integers):

```
train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(    
                        horizontal_flip=horizontal_flip,
                        #rescale=None, #not needed for resnet50
                        preprocessing_function=None, 
                        validation_split=None)

train_dataset = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
                        directory=train_dir,
                        target_size=image_size,
                        class_mode='sparse',
                        batch_size=batch_size,
                        shuffle=True)
```

And the model is a simple resnet50 with a new layer on top:

```
IMG_SHAPE = img_size+(3,)
inputs = Input(shape=IMG_SHAPE, name='image_input',dtype = tf.uint8)
x = tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32)

# not working in this version of keras. inserted in imageGenerator
x = preprocess_input_resnet50(x)

base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(
                                include_top=False, 
                                input_shape = IMG_SHAPE,
                                pooling=None,
                                weights='imagenet')
# Freeze the pretrained weights
base_model.trainable = False
x=base_model(x)

# Rebuild top
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(data_format='channels_last',name="avg_pool")(x)
      
top_dropout_rate = 0.2
x = Dropout(top_dropout_rate, name="top_dropout")(x)
outputs = Dense(num_classes,activation="softmax", name="pred_out")(x)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs,name="ResNet50_comp")

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
        loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
        metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And then I'm calling the fit function:

```
history = model.fit_generator(train_dataset, 
                    steps_per_epoch=n_train_batches, 
                    validation_data=validation_dataset, 
                    validation_steps=n_val_batches,
                    epochs=initial_epochs,
                    verbose=1,
                    callbacks=[stopping])
```

I've reproduced the same behavior for example with the following full script (applied to my dataset and changed to adam and removed intermediate final dense layer):
[deep learning sandbox](https://github.com/DeepLearningSandbox/DeepLearningSandbox/tree/master/transfer_learning)

The easiest way to replicate this behavior was to enable or disable the following line on a `tf2` environment with the same script and add the following line to it. However, I've tested also on `tf1` environments (`1.14` and `1.15`):

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
```

Sadly I cannot provide the dataset.

**Update 26/11/2020**

For full reproducibility I've obtained a similar behaviour by means of the food101 (101 categories) dataset enabling tf1 behaviour with 'tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()'. The following is the script executed with tensorflow-gpu 2.2.0:

```
#%% ref https://medium.com/deeplearningsandbox/how-to-use-transfer-learning-and-fine-tuning-in-keras-and-tensorflow-to-build-an-image-recognition-94b0b02444f2
import os
import sys
import glob
import argparse
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
# enable and disable this to obtain tf1 behaviour
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
from tensorflow.keras import __version__
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50, preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

# since i'm using resnet50 weights from imagenet, i'm using food101 for 
# similar but different categorization tasks
# pip install tensorflow-datasets if tensorflow_dataset not found
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
(train_ds,validation_ds),info= tfds.load('food101', split=['train','validation'], shuffle_files=True, with_info=True)

assert isinstance(train_ds, tf.data.Dataset)
print(train_ds)
#%%
IM_WIDTH, IM_HEIGHT = 224, 224 
NB_EPOCHS = 10
BAT_SIZE = 32



def get_nb_files(directory):
  """Get number of files by searching directory recursively"""
  if not os.path.exists(directory):
    return 0
  cnt = 0
  for r, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for dr in dirs:
      cnt += len(glob.glob(os.path.join(r, dr + "/*")))
  return cnt


def setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model):
  """Freeze all layers and compile the model"""
  for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
  model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])


def add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes):
  """Add last layer to the convnet
  Args:
    base_model: keras model excluding top
    nb_classes: # of classes
  Returns:
    new keras model with last layer
  """
  x = base_model.output
  x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
  #x = Dense(FC_SIZE, activation='relu')(x) #new FC layer, random init
  predictions = Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax')(x) #new softmax layer
  model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
  return model

def train(nb_epoch, batch_size):
  """Use transfer learning and fine-tuning to train a network on a new dataset"""

  #nb_train_samples = train_ds.cardinality().numpy()
  nb_train_samples=info.splits['train'].num_examples
  nb_classes = info.features['label'].num_classes
  classes_names = info.features['label'].names
  #nb_val_samples = validation_ds.cardinality().numpy()
  nb_val_samples = info.splits['validation'].num_examples
  #nb_epoch = int(args.nb_epoch)
  #batch_size = int(args.batch_size)

  def preprocess(features):
      #print(features['image'], features['label'])
      image = tf.image.resize(features['image'], [224,224])
      #image = tf.divide(image, 255)
      #print(image)
      # data augmentation
      image=tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

      image = preprocess_input(image)
      label = features['label']
      # for categorical crossentropy
      #label = tf.one_hot(label,101,axis=-1)
      #return image, tf.cast(label, tf.float32)
      return image, label
  #pre-processing the dataset to fit a specific image size and 2D labelling
  train_generator = train_ds.map(preprocess).batch(batch_size).repeat()
  validation_generator = validation_ds.map(preprocess).batch(batch_size).repeat()

  #train_generator=train_ds
  #validation_generator=validation_ds
  #fig = tfds.show_examples(validation_generator, info)
  # setup model
  base_model = ResNet50(weights='imagenet', include_top=False) #include_top=False excludes final FC layer
  model = add_new_last_layer(base_model, nb_classes)

  # transfer learning
  setup_to_transfer_learn(model, base_model)

  history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=nb_epoch,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//BAT_SIZE,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_val_samples//BAT_SIZE)
    #class_weight='auto')
#execute
history = train(nb_epoch=NB_EPOCHS, batch_size=BAT_SIZE)
```

And the performance on food101 dataset:
[image: acc performance on food101 on differet tf versions]

**update 27/11/2020**

It's possible to see the discrepancy also in the way smaller oxford_flowers102 dataset:

```
(train_ds,validation_ds,test_ds),info= tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', split=['train','validation','test'], shuffle_files=True, with_info=True)
```

[image: oxford_flowers]

Nb: the above plot shows confidences given by running the same training multiple times and evaluatind mean and std to check for the effects on random weights initialization and data augmentation.

Moreover I've tried some hyperparameter tuning on tf2 resulting in the following picture:

- changing optimizer (adam and rmsprop)
- not applying horizontal flipping aumgentation
- deactivating keras resnet50 preprocess_input

[image]

Thanks in advance for every suggestion. Here are the accuracy and validation performance on `tf1` and `tf2` on my dataset:

[image]

**Update 14/12/2020**

I'm sharing the colab for reproducibility on oxford_flowers at the clic of a button:
[colab script](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1C4ABQlYXVg4oXiTLYWofbUriJNb5uHHd?authuser=1#scrollTo=kzX6slkgBNZL)

Comment: Hello. Please don't give a link to the image, rather place the image inside. However, I'm curious to know what makes you downgrade 2 to 1?

Comment: why you set `class_mode` to `int` instead of `sparse`? Can you share some reproducible code?

Comment: Dear @M.Innat thanks for your prompt response. Sparse is the correct configuration, I've corrected it in the post. Thanks for pointing out. I cannot post the image directly until I have 10 reputation points (new to stack overflow). For reproducible code I've linked the deep learning sandbox code that gives similar resulsts(on my dataset). I cannot share my private dataset sadly but I may try it on MNIST in the future and update you with a fully reproducible code.

Comment: Roger. Please share reproducible code with MNIST or any dummy sets. The main problem can be much deeper and without reproducible code, it's hard to debug for others.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Added a new section on the question with the reproducible material applied to food101 (that is the most similar dataset wrt my scenario).

Comment: That's a huge data set to work with!

Comment: I can reproduce the discrepancy also with the oxford_flowers102 (way smaller): `(train_ds,validation_ds,test_ds),info= tfds.load('oxford_flowers102', split=['train','validation','test'], shuffle_files=True, with_info=True)`

Comment: Results differ from each other not only in TF1.x and TF2.x versions, but also in TF2.0 and TF2.2 versions. Probably, it depends on different internal parameters in the packages. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Tfer2, indeed I've checked the features out of the last layer before the dense (as a feature extractor) and found a little discrepancy that was solved after switching back and forth of TF environments because the model weights of the newest TF replaced the ones of the older. However after solving this I still see this huge gap in validation performance.Can only the random initialization of the last dense layer produce such a huge gap and a need of higher time in hyperparameter/architecture tuning in TF1.x?To me it seems more plausible that something more scripty is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I came across something similar, when doing the opposite migration (from TF1+Keras to TF2).

Running this code below:

```
# using TF2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50 
fe = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling="avg")
out = fe.predict(np.ones((1,224,224,3))).flatten()
sum(out)
>>> 212.3205274187726

# using TF1+Keras
import numpy as np 
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50 
fe = ResNet50(include_top=False, pooling="avg") 
out = fe.predict(np.ones((1,224,224,3))).flatten() 
sum(out) 
>>> 187.23898954353717
```

you can see the same model from the same library on different versions does not return the same value (using `sum` as a quick check-up). I found the answer to this mysterious behavior in this other SO answer: [ResNet model in keras and tf.keras give different output for the same image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783361/resnet-model-in-keras-and-tf-keras-give-different-output-for-the-same-image)

Another recommendation I'd give you is, try using `pooling` from inside `applications.resnet50.ResNet50` class, instead of the additional layer in your function, for simplicity, and to remove possible problem-generators :)